# Свои классы и Composer

Tags: php, composer

Скажите пожалуйста, вот например мне нужно написать простенький клас-хелпер, для текста например. Допустим в репозиториях композера нету такого функционала. Куда его правильно класть, что бы автозагрузка подхватылвала ? или нужно оформлять пакет и загружать на packagist? Или в конфиге писать  где мои кастомные классы лежат? извините если несу бред

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас несколько проектов и требуется использовать этот класс в этих проектах, то конечно правильнее его сделать пакетом, ведь это обеспечит удобное управление и обновление. Можете создать собственный внутренний репозиторий с помощью satis, а можете выложить его на всеобщее обозрение на packagist.

Если проект один, то нет смысла создавать пакет, достаточно положить его в одну из папок , где его подхватит Ваш автозагрузчик в соответствии с загрузочными стандартами (PSR-0, PSR-4)

Если у Вас нет автозагрузчика, на packagist сможете найти любой psr4 autoloader и подключить его в boot файл, после чего зарегистрировать пространство имен и удобно работать с подключаемыми файлами.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь знаю куда копать =)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!) У Composer еще вроде как можно использовать встроенный автозагрузчик для загрузки собственных классов из папки проекта с помощью секции autoload в json, я думаю можете найти в интернете информацию по этому вопросу, я просто никогда не пользовался встроенным загрузчиком composer'а для загрузки собственных классов. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload